# Eclipse IDE - info ballons dont work afer hovering a error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I got simple problem - in my eclipse i turned off this helpfull ballons with imports after cursor hovering. And now i dont know how to turn it on, google says nothing about this. Im talking about this :

[image]

[image]

Anyone can help me? This can be silly, but this bubbles are reallly good. Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your preferences under `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Hovers`. You should be able to enable these again in there.

[image]

Comment: This dont work :( But thanks for help, I checked everything and nothing. And the worst, I cant reinsall eclipse :( Again thanks!

Comment: Try cleaning your entire configuration first, maybe you can get it to work this way. Run eclipse with the    
`-clean` command line arg once.